# VB6 - Object was open

Tags: vb6, recordset

I have a recordset, which runs a query:

```
rs.Open "SELECT * FROM Update",objConnection.ActiveCon
Do While Not rs.EOF
  'More logic here.
loop
rs.close
```

The query results are a lot bigger than normal today i.e. 1.5 million rows (rather than the normal, which is about 100000).  I am getting an error when the recordset attempts to open i.e. "Object was open".  What does this mean? I have researched it and the only explanation I can find is that the recordset is too big and there is an error at a lower level of abstraction (because there are too many results).  Is this correct?

**UPDATE 03/06/2012 15:31** 
Firstly, I have found a similar question here: http://www.simple-talk.com/community/forums/thread/59059.aspx.  The answerer quotes the following:

I've never experienced it myself but I gather that it usually happens when you run more than one data flow in parallel which have lookups on the same table The error occurs while resynchronizing a row, but at least one row was successfully resynchronized. The error refers to a storage object that it was trying to open being already open (because, persumably, both lookups share the same buffer area)."

What does he mean by: "run more than one data flow in parallel which have lookups on the same table".  Is he referring to two different processes updating the same table?

Secondly, I am wandering if there is a limit on the size of the Windows process.  If the limit is exceeded then the error appears?

Comment: Perhaps you opened the recordset twice, without first closing it.

Comment: @ta.speot.is, I have never seen this error before.  The application has run for years.  Today there is an unusual volume of records to process.  The recordset is not opened twice by me.

Comment: Have you tried retrieving only few records from your query and checked if it works? There may be a limit for storing record in the recordset.

Comment: @Nick, yes the query works if I select 5000000 rows or less.

Comment: What is your database backend (Access, MSSQL)? The error could come from the source of your data. Also, post the full error with error number, description and line on which it failed.